# ajax: responsetext returns my entire php code locally

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, response

I found a good Tutorial: [tutorial](http://www.webmasterpro.de/coding/article/einfuehrung-ajax.html)

but it doesn't work locally. 
The Problem is, that the responsetext returns my entire php code. 
I double-click at my ajaxclock.html and use Firefox.
Surprisingly, it works on the server.

Here the code:
ajaxclock.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>AJAX Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="time"></div>
    <button onclick="getTime();">Aktualisieren</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var req = getXmlHttpRequestObject();
window.onload = getTime();

function getXmlHttpRequestObject()
{
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {
         return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else if(window.ActiveXObject) 
    {
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } 
    else 
    {
        alert('Ajax funktioniert bei Ihnen nicht!');
    }
}

function getTime()
{
    if(req.readyState == 4 || req.readyState == 0) 
    {
        req.open('GET', 'ajaxclock.php', true);
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","text/plain");
        req.onreadystatechange = setMessage;
        req.send(null);
    }
}

function setMessage()
{
    if(req.readyState == 4) 
    {
        var response = eval('(' + req.responseText+ ')');
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = response.time;
    }
}
```

ajaxclock.php

```
<?php echo '{"time": "'.date("H:i:s").'"}'; ?>
```

Comment: of course PHP needs the server to process PHP directives. otherwise, without a server, AJAX just returns whatever was written in the file!

Comment: Why is that code setting the request's Content-Type to `text/plain` when there is no message body at all?

Comment: This isn't a good tutorial, it makes use of a global `req` variable. There is no reason to use globals for this.

Comment: For me, The problem was that I didn't use the php opening and closing tags " <?php " and  " ?> " , I added them and it fiwed the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Surprisingly, it works on the server.

PHP is a server side technology. It will only ever work on a server (specifically a server configured to run PHP programs).

If you use it without such a server then nothing will execute the PHP and it will be delivered to the browser in its raw state.

Comment: Yup. I faced this problem before. The problem was PHP library was not parsing was not working and therefore Apache server was reading the php file as html and returning it's source code

Comment: Install a webserver that supports PHP on your development system. Run your code through that over `http://localhost/…`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Did not find any reason until I realized that the LiveServer Plugin in Firefox (97.0.1 (64-Bit)) didn't execut the php file. For whatever reason. I use XAMPP (v.3.2.4) and tried it the "old" way via: *localhost/project/index.php* and it worked fine for me again.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31167653)