# how can an extension interact with a DB without forcing the users to install a server and php

Tags: php, javascript, database, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome extension which sends some data to a PHP file, which then the PHP file sends it to a database.

All is fine and well, but I just wanted to ask if my users need to have PHP as well as a server installed on their machines, for the extension to work?

According to some posts it does (for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186009/ajax-responsetext-returns-my-entire-php-code-locally)). But if this indeed the case, then how can an extension interact with a database without forcing the users to install a server and PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php is a server side scripting language, meaning that all of the processing is done on your server. there is no reason that any user would need to install anything in able to access a php application.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into WebSQL (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_SQL_Database).
It's not developed anymore (and stays unfinished), but according to this Wikipedia article it's based on SQLite and chrome supports is.

Comment: Recommending [an abandoned spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#status-of-this-document) probably isn't the greatest idea, given that IndexedDB is now used in WebSQL's place.

Comment: I didn't know about IndexedDB. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can interact with a database (IndexedDB) using JS in your extension.

Resources:

- [Can I use...](http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb)
- [IndexedDB | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB)

Since you are making a Chrome extension, there may not be any concern for cross-browser support, but according to [HTML5 Please](http://html5please.com/#indexeddb), a polyfill is recommended.