# AJAX GET returns the php script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get

I have a very simple hello world ajax-php example that returns as a result the whole php script. here's the code:

### client code:

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "text",
        url: "hello-world.php",
        success: function(data){
            $("#myDiv").text(data);
            console.log(data);
        }

    });
```

---

### server code:

```
<?php
// A simple web site in Cloud9 that runs through Apache
// Press the 'Run' button on the top to start the web server,
// then click the URL that is emitted to the Output tab of the console

echo 'Hello world!';

?>
```

---

### here's the console log:

```
<?php
// A simple web site in Cloud9 that runs through Apache
// Press the 'Run' button on the top to start the web server,
// then click the URL that is emitted to the Output tab of the console

echo 'Hello world!';

?>
```

thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that PHP is enabled on the server? if you open hello-world.php directly in the browser what do you see?

Comment: the script runs when accessed directly and does print "Hello World!". I am using cloud9 workspace to run this example.

Comment: Zakiya, what is your expected output ??

Comment: are you calling AJAX the same URL, i.e. 'the URL that is emitted to the Output tab of the console'?

Answer (score 2):

As per @DavidRiccitelli - it looks like you're not running php and apache is just serving up the file rather than passing it to PHP to be executed.

Try [WAMP](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://www.wampserver.com/en/&ei=iNlzUrTqIIm7kgW82oBo&usg=AFQjCNFO33ha831rcBcg26auReVm9E2Dtw&sig2=D7BpMReF1qaoAXPhUnNnVQ&bvm=bv.55819444,d.dGI) server of [XAMPP](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html&ei=qdlzUv22K4G0kgW_nYHwDw&usg=AFQjCNGc5NLvRxcZrB8MRP6RiYtrUCzJBg&sig2=BaWZYuO3TC-PKnJxIdamdQ&bvm=bv.55819444,d.dGI) for bundled server packages on windows
[MAMP](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://www.mamp.info/&ei=yNlzUtDGKcebkgWxn4G4Dw&usg=AFQjCNE3Eeh78-JAsRygzNjtPVbj-miJkQ&sig2=CllhMfdXt3ZtGqL34ZFsdA&bvm=bv.55819444,d.dGI) for MacOSX etx

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your PHP isn't being interpreted, and thus is being returned as raw HTML.

Check [here for a similar issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186009/ajax-responsetext-returns-my-entire-php-code-locally)