# php not executing after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to save a txt file from javascript by letting ajax call a php script. The callback is successful, however the php is not being executed. Also, running the php script in terminal will create my txt file. So somehow the call is not getting executed? What am I doing wrong?

The javascript:

```
var data = "test"
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/saver.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { data: data },
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result);},
    error: function(result) {
        alert('ERROR');}
        });
```

The php script:

```
<?php

$data = $_POST['data'];
$fp = fopen('path/hs2.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: can you add `console.log(result)` just to check?

Comment: Can you show me the file structure? and where these both files (file which has ajax and the end php file) are?

Comment: @FirstOne: it shows the php script

Comment: @Akshay: they are in the same folder actually

Comment: What do you mean the php script? the source code?

Comment: @j08691 maybe permissions aren't ok. What should I add? Shebang? And some kind of chmod?

Comment: @Ansjovis86
Set permissions as `777` to *check it's working*.

Comment: You can chmod it to 0777 temporarily

Comment: @FirstOne it prints exactly the same thing as the contents of the php script

Comment: Check these questions: [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page) **&&** [Apache shows php code instead of executing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing) **&&** [**ajax: responsetext returns my entire php code locally**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186009/ajax-responsetext-returns-my-entire-php-code-locally)

Comment: @j08691: permissions appear not to be the problem

Comment: Just to test, replace what you have now (but not the POST array) with an echo for it, see if something gets echo'd.

Comment: @FirstOne it might help if I read the comments ;)

Comment: "It shows the php script" -- Is your WAMP server even running?

Comment: If it shows the PHP script, then if you're accessing this as `file:///file.xxx` in your browser, then that's the problem. Is PHP installed? running off a host? doesn't seem to be parsing to me. If local, use `http://localhost/file.xxx`

Comment: I changed all file and folder permissions. This is definitely not the problem. This script is being run locally and deals with local files.

Comment: [This is the comment that needs addressing...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38678918/php-not-executing-after-ajax-call#comment64737636_38678918) as to "how" it's accessed (2 different animals). The question's short on detail here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- PHP is installed (I can run it in terminal). The html file in which the ajax part is included is running locally on my computer. Trying the localhost url is resulting now in calback errors on ajax.

Comment: I've put in the full javascript now. So you can try at home ;)

Comment: Alright, to clear things out: replace `$_POST['data']` with `'some string'` and access the php script **from the browser**. You should access something like `localhost/saver.php` (put the correct path to the php file, just make sure the url does **not** start with `file:///`)

Comment: Ok, the html that I run has indeed a path with   file:///path/myscript.html . I cannot seem to switch properly to localhost. It is saying OSX is not recognizing adresses starting with "localhost".

Comment: @FirstOne So what was this story about WAMP or MAMP? I might need that, no?

Comment: Yeah that did the trick. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

It's a path issue in `fopen(...)`. Change it to:

```
$fp = fopen('hs2.txt', 'w');
```

`fopen()` cannot create a file in a folder that doesn't exist. You are trying to create a file in a non-existent nested folder.

Comment: no that appears not to be the problem

Comment: You tested it and doesn't work? For me it works fine. I don't understand.

Comment: @Ansjovis86 you said the files are in the same folder, so why are you using `'path/saver.php'`?

Comment: Yes exactly. `fopen()` doesn't create directories. With `fopen('path/hs2.txt')` you are trying to create a file in path `./path/path/hs2.txt` but the nested folder doesn't exist.

Comment: if that's the case then, error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php would have triggered an error.